# Logging on to Microsoft SQL Server fail with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am just installing a new server which rely on Microsoft SQL Server 2014, and I have an issue.

I can connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio without any problem. I created a user, granted him rights (way too much, but w/e). But when I try the website, it says me "Login failed for user 'user'."

And I don't understand why :(

My asp.net connection string is:

```
<add name="MsSQLConnString" 
     connectionString="Server=VPS85385\SQLEXPRESS; Database=kinpro;User Id=user;Password=1992;Connect Timeout=90;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In Management Studio, this user has the "user mapping" to the DB I want access. Under Securables, it has the "connect SQL" permission ...

I don't know why it is not working.

I hope one of you have a clue about this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you log in from SSMS using that user/password?

Comment: Nop, it says "Login failed for user 'user'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)"

Comment: That's the first thing you need to take care of. If SSMS won't let you log in, ASP certainly won't.  Post a screen shot of the user properties?

Comment: Which page of user properties ? 
Server roles ? User mapping ? Excuse me if my questions are stupids, it's the first time I use this software :x

Comment: No worries. Since its your first time, log in however you can, then bring up the user and set the password again. Maybe you made a mistake.

Comment: Probably something silly. Screen shot of user properties where you set username and password?

Answer (score 0):

I'm soooooo sorry... seems like a reboot of the service was enough to fix my problem. 
I am ashamed !